# High opendirectoryd CPU usage caused by Qustodio- Any Fix?

Tags: battery, performance, cpu, daemons, open-directory

I have an 14" M1 Max that gets very poor battery life, which I suspect is mainly due to the installed internet filter, Qustodio, causing high CPU usage from opendirectoryd. As per activity monitor, opendirectoryd is constantly using ~20% CPU, but can spike to 40. There is a very causal relationship between opendirectoryd usage and Qustodio. If Qustodio is uninstalled, the usage disappears, and there is an instant spike in usage the moment Qustodio is reinstalled. Opening the console, I see no error messages relating either to opendirectoryd or to Qustodio.

Unfortunately, that is as far as I was able to figure out on my own. I don't know why Qustodio is causing such high opendirectoryd usage, nor do I know how to fix it. **What should I do to investigate further, and what can possibly be done do fix it?**

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to [contact the developers](https://www.qustodio.com/en/) of the software in question and relay your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not a bug. Qustodio is simply designed so that it makes a lot of queries that are handled by `opendirectoryd`.

In order to get better battery life, you would want to either find a competing product to use instead of Qustodio, or contact Qustudio to request that they improve the performance of their program in a later version.